# Android Push notifications component

Tags: android, push-notification

I need to implement a server that can send Push Notifications to Android mobile phones.
I am looking for a component that provide push notifications services, I dont mind paying for a good one. 
Where do I start if I want to implement my own?

Thanks

Amit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android C2DM is not what you are looking for?